# Laravel Route with n parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have categories and each category can have subcategories.

So I have this route:

```
Route::get('category/{param1}/{param2?}', 'CategoryController@show');
```

But what when a child category also has subcategories and so on? Is there a way to do it without hardcoding the number of possible subs?

For the controller I could use the splat operator like this:

```
public function show(...$param) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to accept it as a single route segment, then split it up yourself:

```php
Route::get('category/{params}', 'CategoryController@show')->where('params', '.*');
```

```php
public function show($params) {
    $params = explode('/', $params);
}
```

Comment: worked :). But I thought with the new splat operator the Laravel developers would make a better solution for this problem so you don't need to use the `explode()` function.